# Цикл продолжает выполнятся только пока страница открыта в браузере. Возможно ли сделать, чтобы он выполнялся постоянно?

Tags: python

Есть такой вопрос:
На хостинге запускаю скрипт на Python с бесконечным циклом

```
while True:
    #do somethink
```

Перехожу по адресу скрипта, и цикл продолжает выполнятся только пока страница открыта в браузере.
Возможно ли сделать, чтобы он выполнялся постоянно?

Comment: похоже, что вы пытаетесь решить какую-то более глобальную задачу, для которой выбрали решение в виде запуска бесконечного цикла. расскажите о *глобальной* задаче — вполне вероятно, что у неё есть и другие решения.

Comment: Я написал бота для ВК, и хотел бы, чтобы он работал независимо

Comment: возможно, ответы на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1423345/4827341) вам помогут.

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, в виде ответа на свой вопрос, какое именно решение вам помогло. это поможет другим людям с аналогичной проблемой быстрее её решить.

Comment: Если хочешь, чтобы он работал бесконечно, нужно запускать скрипт через crontab, например

Answer (score 2):

скорее всего - нет, нельзя
вы запускаете скрипт, переходя по его адресу, после чего закрываете его, тем самым останавливаете цикл.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?